# (C++) Variable value changing when I call a function

Tags: c++

I have the following code

NCore.h

```
#ifndef _NCORE_H_
#define _NCORE_H_

#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

namespace Neat
{
    class NCore
    {
    private:
        // Structure Definitions
        struct NApplicationVersion
        {
            int major = 0;
            int minor = 0;
            int build = 0;
            LPCSTR toString();
        };

        // Application Variables
        LPCSTR applicationName;
        NApplicationVersion applicationVersion;

    protected:


    public:
        NCore();

        LPCSTR ApplicationName(LPCSTR _applicationName = NULL);
        NApplicationVersion ApplicationVersion(LPCSTR _applicationVersion = NULL);
    };
}

#endif
```

NCore.cpp

```
#include "NCore.h"

Neat::NCore::NCore()
{
    this->applicationName = NULL;
}

LPCSTR Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion::toString()
{
    char str[16];
    memset(&str, 0, sizeof(str));
    sprintf_s(str, sizeof(str), "%i.%i.%i", this->major, this->minor, this->build);
    return str;
}

LPCSTR Neat::NCore::ApplicationName(LPCSTR _applicationName)
{
    if (_applicationName)
        this->applicationName = _applicationName;
    return this->applicationName;
}

Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion Neat::NCore::ApplicationVersion(LPCSTR _applicationVersion)
{
    if (_applicationVersion)
    {
            //I know this isn't needed. I was just testing something.
        Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion *nav = (Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion *)malloc(sizeof(Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion));
        sscanf_s(_applicationVersion, "%i.%i.%i", &nav->major, &nav->minor, &nav->build);
        this->applicationVersion.major = nav->major;
        this->applicationVersion.minor = nav->minor;
        this->applicationVersion.build = nav->build;
            free(nav);
    }
    return this->applicationVersion;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include "NCore.h"

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT iCmdShow)
{
    Neat::NCore n;
    n.ApplicationName("test");
    LPCSTR test = n.ApplicationName();

    LPCSTR test2 = n.ApplicationVersion().toString();
    if (strcmp(test2, "0.0.0") == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "", "", MB_OK);
    }
    n.ApplicationVersion("10.50.136");
    if (strcmp(test2, "0.0.0") == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "", "", MB_OK);
    }
    LPCSTR test3 = n.ApplicationVersion().toString();
    if (test3 == "10.50.136")
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "", "", MB_OK);
    }

    while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that test2 initializes as "0.0.0" and the first MessageBox is shown. But after I call ApplicationVersion("10.50.136") it changes test2 to "10.50.136" and the second MessageBox is not shown.

Can someone please explain why this happens/how to fix it?

EDIT: I was testing a function that could operate as both a get/set function. I'm fairly new to this and I learn by failing. I just can't figure out what exactly went wrong here.

EDIT 2: I changed the code as follows...

NCore.h

```
struct NApplicationVersion
{
    int major = 0;
    int minor = 0;
    int build = 0;
    char asString[16];
    LPCSTR toString();
};
```

NCore.cpp

```
LPCSTR Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion::toString()
{
    memset(this->asString, 0, 15);
    sprintf_s(this->asString, 16, "%i.%i.%i", this->major, this->minor, this->build);
    return this->asString;
}
```

Is this viable?

From my understanding, I was putting the variable "str" on the stack. This causes it to not have a set place in memory(?) and when other calls altered the stack they also altered the data the pointer "test2" was trying to read from?

Comment: The surprise is it works at all.  Returning a pointer to a variable that goes out of scope is undefined behavior.

Comment: It happens because a call such as `n.ApplicationVersion("10.50.136")` is designed to set the version - what do you expect `this->applicationVersion.major = nav->major; this->applicationVersion.minor = nav->minor;
this->applicationVersion.build = nav->build;` to do?  How is that broken or in need of a fix?  If you don't want to set it, don't call.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: which function/variable's that?

Comment: @TonyD : `Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion::toString()` is returning `str`, which is declared as `char str[16]`, local to that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy, actually.  `toString` invokes undefined behavior by returning an array (`str`) that's allocated locally to the function and goes out of scope with the `return`:

```
LPCSTR Neat::NCore::NApplicationVersion::toString()
{
    char str[16];
    memset(&str, 0, sizeof(str));
    sprintf_s(str, sizeof(str), "%i.%i.%i", this->major, this->minor, this->build);
    return str;
}
```

In most common C++ implementations, `str` will be on the stack.  (The C++ standard does not require a unified concept of "stack" where all automatic variables live, but most common implementations work that way.)

So, subsequent functions that modify the stack will also modify the C-style string pointed to by the call to `toString()`.  The subsequent call to `n.ApplicationVersion()`, for example, would likely trash `str`.  Your second message box won't show as long as the string changed to anything other than "0.0.0", and it won't take much to corrupt the stack in that way.

---

Based on your subsequent edit:  Making the string a member of your class will *somewhat* work.  Any call to `toString` will rewrite this string, affecting all callers that saved a pointer to this buffer.

Still, this is certainly much safer than saving the string on the stack.  Furthermore, as long as only `toString` writes to this buffer, you have well defined rules for when that string is valid.

Comment: It's worth noting that this could just as well happen with a member variable, since the caller is just copying the pointer instead of actually copying the string (as @Mikhail's answer points out).

Comment: I'm slightly confused because the second call of toString() isn't what causes the issue. It's the call right after the first MessageBox.

Comment: That is true.  In this particular case, I believe the `strcmp` in the middle fails because the string got garbaged.  But you're correct:  If you want a durable string on return, you must return storage that doesn't go out of scope with `return` and is not going to be modified by later method calls.

Comment: @user3105785 : The array `str` is likely on the stack.  Nearly _any_ function call will corrupt that string, causing your `strcmp(test2, "0.0.0")` to fail.

Comment: @s.ribich95 : I reworded my answer slightly to make it clearer.  I also added a second section to respond to the edit in your original question.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`LPCSTR` is not the string, it is just the pointer to the char array. When you set new version, the char array itself is changing. That's why you observer the change in `test2` variable immediately. If you want this string not to be changed, copy and save it in your internal buffer.